# What is the opposite of a tail recursive solution?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm solving problem 4 in the [99 problems of Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html) and I'm still learning OCaml

Question 4 reads

> OCaml standard library has List.length but we ask that you reimplement it. Bonus for a tail recursive solution.

So as per my understanding a recursive solution merits bonus points because it more efficient than a potentially easier more verbose solution

I came up with this for a tail recursive solution

```
let length in_list =
  let rec find_len cur_length = function
  | [] -> cur_length
  | hd::tl -> find_len (cur_length + 1) tl
  in find_len 0 in_list
;;
```

And as per my understanding of tail recursion this is valid because it operates recursively on the tail

**My question is what is the opposite of this? What is a valid non tail recursive solution**

I guess it would be something that operates recursively on the head of the list
I came up with

```
let hd_rec_length in_list =
  let rec pop_last saved_list= function
  | [] -> saved_list
  | [last] -> saved_list
  | hd::tl -> pop_last (saved_list@[hd]) tl
  in 
    let rec hd_rec_find_len cur_length in_list =
    match in_list with  
      | [] -> cur_length
      | hd::tl -> hd_rec_find_len (cur_length+1) (pop_last [] in_list)
      in hd_rec_find_len 0 in_list
;;
```

But my gut tells me I'm missing something more obvious than this and the second solution seems like too much work and the first seems more natural and easy, what am I missing?

Comment: Tail recursive means not relying on the function call stack. But you still need a structure to store the intermediate results of each tail recursive step. `cur_length` is such a structure, an accumulator, which substitutes the call stack. So the opposite of accumulator-style tail recursion is recursion that relies on the function call stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tail-recursive function is a recursive function where all recursive calls happen in a tail position. What that means is that the recursive call must be the last thing that happens in any given path through the function. All of the recursive functions in your question are tail recursive.

Tail recursion does not mean recursing on the tail of the list. In fact a tail recursive function doesn't have to involve lists at all.

So a non-tail recursive function would be any function where you do anything after the recursive call (or there are even multiple recursive calls that aren't mutually exclusive). Usually that means applying some other function to the result of the recursive function after the recursive function returns.

A non-tail recursive version of `length` would be:

```
let rec length = function
| [] -> 0
| _::tl -> 1 + length tl
```

This is not tail-recursive because the last thing that happens here is the addition, not the call to `length`. So after the recursive call returns, we add 1 to its result and *then* we return as well.

Comment: but are you not recursing on the tail here? also shouldn't  this functon be a `rec`

Comment: @Srini That's not what "tail recursive" means. Let me amend my answer.

Comment: I do not know of ocaml but,  in this example, compared to your @Srini, the computation status does not goes with the recursion and, once you have reached the end of the list, you have to return on your step to calculate its length. You go at the end, states there is not any other element `[] _> 0`  and then start your way back to the first computation frame adding one for every step you take back. In your solution you check the elements as you go and when you reach the end you have the result ready.

Comment: Oh, I see, so if you were to visualize the recursion calls as a tree in a tail recursive  calls go down to a leaf and break out, but non tail recursive solutions go down to a leaf and come back to the root,

Comment: @sepp2k a side note, shouldn't length be a `let rec` in your solution?

Comment: @Srini Yes, it should. Fixed. And yes, you're exactly right about the tree visualization. Basically tail recursion means that once you reach the leaf, you don't have to go back, so it can be optimized to not need a call stack.